# Displaying different currency amounts

Tags: picklist, multi-currency

I have enabled our multiple currency feature in order to update multiple currency rate values. We want to give a user the ability to view a field's value in another field in which they decide the currency.

In other words, they would fill out a field called "Revenue" which would always be displayed in USD. They would then choose a currency in a picklist field ("International Currency") - and an equivalent currency amount would be displayed in another number field ("International Revenue"). The "International Revenue" amount would be calculated based on the currency's current rate according to the "Revenue" (USD value).

I would like to display the "International Currency" (picklist) and the "International Revenue" (number) together in one field (ie "GBP 1,200,000.00").

What is the best way to go about doing that ? It seems more difficult to do with a simple text formula field if I want the number to be displayed properly (commas etc).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: this is not supported OOTB; the SFDC currency formatting relies on the value within `CurrencyIsoCode`

Answer (score 1):

This would need custom work. You could create a component (either ApexComponent for VF Page or LWC Component for Lightning) which accepts base value in USD and currency. That component can query APEX to get the exchange rate and show the converted value.

You could leverage typically formatting rules to format the number. If you are targeting modern browsers, you can also leverage [Intl module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). You could also use [lightning-formatted-number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/example) if you are building LWC component.